# centos 7 AWS (login with ssh-key AND password)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, authentication, centos

I want to login with ssh into my Centos 7 AWS machine using ssh-key **and** password.

But when i ssh into my machine I get logged in without being prompted for a password.

My situation:

- AMI: CentOS 7 (x86_64) - with Updates HVM
- I disabled root login and created *user1* to login with ssh
- *user1* ~/.ssh has permissions: 0700
- *user1* ~/.ssh/authorized_keys has permissions: 0600
- *user1* belongs to the wheel group
- a password is set for *user1*
- sshd_conf:

```
Match User user1
        PasswordAuthentication yes
        PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: If your key is in `authorized_keys`, no password will be required. If you want to use a password to unlock your key so that if someone steals your key they won't be able to ssh your machine, then generate a password protected key with `ssh-keygen` and use that one.

Comment: What do you mean by login "using ssh-key and password" ? On a given login, it can be either via key or via password.

Comment: I assume that he means he want both a valid key *and* a valid password to be provided before the user authentication succeeds. Both.

Comment: @the_storyteller Your first answer answered my question. In addition to the public key I wanted a password to be required.
I generated a password-protected ssh-key and this worked. thank you

Comment: @iamauser I was misunderstanding the way ssh asks for a password. I  figured the password of user1 itself would be used. But apparently it is set while creating the ssh-key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your key is in `authorized_keys`, no password will be required.

If you want to use a password to unlock your key so that if someone steals your key they won't be able to ssh your machine, then generate a password protected key with `ssh-keygen` and use that one.

Then you can force ssh key authentication by setting `PasswordAuthentication no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
```

This way the user will be forced both to use a key, and to unlock that key with a password.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prefer one authentication method over another, while you have both available, you can use the option for ssh `PreferredAuthentications`.

When you have ssh-keys available, but you want to SSH using password, use the following command

```
 ~]# ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password <server>
```

This will prompt you for a password to be entered before login succeeds.